# Syntax highlighting for shell code blocks when exporting org-mode files to Latex using listings

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm using the LaTeX package listings for exporting code blocks in org-mode to latex files.

I've defined a latex template with the =org-latex-classes= feature as described in https://so.nwalsh.com/2020/01/05-latex .

This works well for python code blocks, i.e.

```
#+begin_src python
import pandas as pd
#+end_src
```

However, org-mode uses the "shell" keyword to define "sh/bash" code block. The "shell" keyword is not defined for the LaTeX listings package (but "sh" and "bash" is). Thus, exporting org-mode "shell" code blocks does not work, i.e:

```
#+begin_src shell
conda install pandas -y
#+end_src
```

does not work.

Is there a workaround to either make listings accept the "shell" keyword, or org-mode to accept "sh"/"bash" as keywords?

Comment: You *can* say `#+begin_src bash  ...` or `#+begin_src sh...` instead of `shell`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.